# Chunk an array of objects and add empty arrays at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to chunk an array of objects so i write:

```
function conditionalChunk(array, size, rules = {}) {
    let copy = [...array],
        output = [],
        i = 0;

    while (copy.length)
        output.push(copy.splice(0, rules[i++] ?? size))


    return output
}
```

and it works fine if I have rules like { 0: 2, 1: 2 }

```
 const input = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]],
                output = conditionalChunk(input.flat(), 3, { 0: 2, 1: 2 });
          
    // OUTPUT: [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

but when I have rules at the end like { 0: 2, 1: 2, 2:0, 5:0 } my function ignore to create empty arrays at the end.

the output I need is:

```
const input = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]],
                    output = conditionalChunk(input.flat(), 3, { 0: 2, 1: 2, 2:0, 5:0 });
              
        // OUTPUT: [[1,2],[3,4],[],[5,6,7],[]]
```

so I just need to not ignore rules for empty arrays at the end of array. How I can do that?

Comment: what happens to the array at index `5` in the result set?

Comment: it should be add at the end of array as empty, not need to be at position 5

Comment: in `rule`, it could be also `4` or any larger value to get an empty array at the end, right?

Comment: yes, it could be 10: 0

Comment: Your code is actually working as intended. The problem with needing empty arrays after `copy` is empty is a function call like `const input
= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]], output = conditionalChunk(input.flat(), 3, { 0: 2, 1: 2, 2:0, 7:0 });` would now be legitimate

Comment: @fxtrot that wont add empty array at the end

Comment: @AleksPer a workaround is switching the `while` loop so that it checks to see if all chunks are successfully created and if not continues churning out chunks until it meets the requirements. Let me work on a much more solid answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fe1bvhaw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, you could check the keys of `rules` and if greater or equal to the next index of `output` push an empty array.

```js
function conditionalChunk(array, size, rules = {}) {
    let output = [],
        i = 0;

    while (i < array.length)
        output.push(array.slice(i, i += rules[output.length] ?? size));
    
    let l = Object.keys(rules).reduce((l, v) => l + (v >= output.length), 0);

    while (l--) output.push([]);

    return output;
}

console.log(conditionalChunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3, { 0: 2, 1: 2 })); // [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]
console.log(conditionalChunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3, { 0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 0, 5: 0 })); // [[1,2],[3,4],[],[5,6,7],[]]
console.log(conditionalChunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3, { 0: 0, 1: 2, 8: 0, 7: 0, 9:0, 20:0 }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this, I prefer `for...each` loop in place of a `while`.

```
function conditionalChunk(array, size = 1, rules = {}) {
    let copy = [...array],
        output = [],
        i = 0;


        for (const rule of Object.keys(rules)) {
            let val = copy.splice(0, rules[rule] || size);
      if (typeof val === 'undefined') val = [];
      
      output.push(val);
    }

    return output;
}

var results = conditionalChunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, { 0:2, 1: 2, 2:2, 3:0 });

console.log(results, '::results::');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ozbj7na/

Comment: Code dont work for rules like: 
var results = conditionalChunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, { 0:0, 1: 2, 2:2, 11:0, 10:0 }); ... seems that do not create empty at the start ...

Comment: This wont work when rules is empty

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem would be to add this bit of code after the `while` loop before the `return` statement

```js
output.length = Math.max.apply(null, [output.length, ...Object.keys(rules)]) || output.length;
    
for (r in rules)
{
    output[r] = new Array(rules[r]);
}
```

It just extends the output array to the desired length then populates required spots with empty arrays (sorry for the complicated first line but JavaScript is complicated so :| ...)

Comment: I will test now

Comment: @AleksPer sure thing. I hope it works (at least on my end it does)

Comment: console.log(conditionalChunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3, { 0: 0, 1: 2, 8: 0, 7: 0, 9:0, 20:0 }));

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, this should work for you and is done based on your solution, so it should be easier to understand

```
  function conditionalChunk(array, size, rules = {}) {
  let copy = [...array],
    output = [],
    i = 0;

  while (copy.length) output.push(copy.splice(0, rules[i++] ?? size));

  const arr = Object.keys(rules).filter((key) => key > i);

  arr.forEach((key) => {
    if (rules[key] === 0) output.push([]);
  });

  return output;
}
```